# \hrule with indents in Plain TeX

Tags: indentation, rules, plain-tex

I am trying to learn the 'metal' of TeX after 20 years of using higher level packages, such as LaTeX.

In my test document I have an indented block representing simple recipes. I've created this with two macros, for the beginning and end of a recipe:

```
\def\beginrecipe{
  \par
  \begingroup
  \leftskip=\baselineskip
  \multiply\leftskip by 2
  \rightskip=\leftskip
  \parindent=-\baselineskip
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \reciperule
}
\def\endrecipe{
  \par
  \reciperule
  \endgroup
}
```

I want the recipe blocks to have horizontal rules at the top and bottom, so I've defined my `\reciperule` command to be:

```
\def\reciperule{
  \vskip0.5em\hrule\vskip0.5em
}
```

In the document this is used something like:

```
\beginrecipe
{\bf Blonde roux}

2 tbsp of butter.

2 tbsp of flour.

Melt the butter in a pan and add the flour.

Cook the flour without browning for 2 minutes, stirring with a whisk.
\endrecipe
```

This works well, but the `\hrule` is too wide. It spans the width of the text-block, I want it to just fill the width of the recipe. So it should start `\baselineskip` in from the left, and extend to `\baselineskip` from the right.

I've tried to do this with `\hskip\baselineskip` and using `\hrulefill` to fill the available space. The problem is `\hskip` reserves a line worth of height, which is far too much, I want the rule to be thin.

Can I either indent an `\hrule` (I know I can set its width, so this would work), or can I get `\hskip`, `\hrulefill`, etc, to have a specified height?

Or is there an easier way to do the whole thing (that doesn't use a package beyond Plain TeX)?

Comment: Could you add a minimal example to play with?

Comment: Yes, just added an example of it, in use. A full minimal example file is at: https://gist.github.com/idmillington/7827067

Comment: Try `\nointerlineskip` before and after the rule made with `\hrulefill`.

Comment: `\halign` is your friend my friend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `\moveright` a box with a rule in it, but also to watch out against page breaks before the rule

```
\def\beginrecipe{
  \par
  \begingroup
  \leftskip=\baselineskip
  \multiply\leftskip by 2
  \rightskip=\leftskip
  \parindent=-\baselineskip
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \nobreak
  \reciperule
}
\def\endrecipe{
  \par\nobreak
  \reciperule
  \endgroup
}
\def\reciperule{
  \nointerlineskip
  \vskip0.5em
  \moveright\baselineskip\vbox{
    \advance\hsize-3\baselineskip
    \hrule width \hsize
  }
  \nointerlineskip
  \nobreak
  \vskip0.5em
}

\beginrecipe
{\bf Blonde roux}

2 tbsp of butter.

2 tbsp of flour.

Melt the butter in a pan and add the flour.

Cook the flour without browning for 2 minutes, stirring with a whisk.
Cook the flour without browning for 2 minutes, stirring with a whisk.
\endrecipe

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect drop in replacement, thanks @egreg, and --even better-- understandable!

Answer (score 5):

Please always post complete documents not fragments.

You either need to use a rule *within* a paragraph so it automatically obeys the paragraph settings like `\leftskip` or you need to move it across by `\leftskip` "by hand".

This shows the original and both approaches (which have different effects on vertical space)

*update: I just noticed you (somewhat strangely?) have a negative parindent If you want the rule to line up with the text you will need to change the `\noindent` to `\indent`
so it is similarly moved left.*

[image]

```
\def\beginrecipe{
  \par
  \begingroup
  \leftskip=\baselineskip
  \multiply\leftskip by 2
  \rightskip=\leftskip
  \parindent=-\baselineskip
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \reciperule
  \reciperulea
  \reciperuleb
}
\def\endrecipe{
  \par
  \reciperule
  \reciperulea
  \reciperuleb
  \endgroup
}

I want the recipe blocks to have horizontal rules at the top and bottom, so I've defined my reciperule command to be:

\def\reciperule{
  \vskip0.5em\hrule\vskip0.5em
}


\def\reciperulea{
  \vskip0.5em\noindent\hrulefill\hbox{}\par\vskip0.5em
}
\def\reciperuleb{
  \vskip0.5em
   \dimen0\hsize
   \advance\dimen0-\leftskip
   \advance\dimen0-\rightskip
   \moveright\leftskip\vbox{\hrule width\dimen0}
}

In the document this is used something like:

\beginrecipe
{\bf Blonde roux}

2 tbsp of butter.

2 tbsp of flour.

Melt the butter in a pan and add the flour.

Cook the flour without browning for 2 minutes, stirring with a whisk.
\endrecipe

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on full documents. I'll do that next time, for sure. The negative par indent is so that the follow on lines of a step in a recipe is indented in. So it is easy to see the first line of a new step. Using your reciperuleb approach I still get the funky spacing, egreg's answer tweaks adds the extra incantations, so I'll accept that. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ian It is better to use `\hangindent` (or `\hang`) or plain tex `\item` to get that.