# indenting or centering \hrule

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I am trying to print two horizontal lines to look like a divider in an older book. Using `\hrule` with slightly different widths and lengths makes the lines look hand laid.

But trying to use `\moveleft` or `\nointerlineskip` suggested in [centered `hrule`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300351/centered-hrule-plain-tex) I get an error saying it cant be done in horizontal mode. The question [`hrule` with indents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148704/hrule-with-indents-in-plain-tex) is similar, but if so, I can't figure out how to apply the information. I get errors with \indent and \item, etc.

I'd like to understand how to fix `\hrule`, but answer using rule or some other command would be fine, too.

This is the code I am using, and it compiles, but every attempted adjustment leads to noncompiling.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    %\usepackage{fontspec}
    %\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
    %\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \normalfont\large Some Text Above 
    \vspace{9pt}
    \hrule height .8pt width .870\textwidth
    \vspace{14pt}
    \hrule height 1.1pt width .877\textwidth
    \vspace{6pt}
    1 6 4 7.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `\rule` and `\leavevmode` is the accumulation of `\baselineskip` between each baseline.  In this solution, you can remove all the 0pt terms and see that they line up precisely.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    %\usepackage{fontspec}
    %\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}% Please don't make me download another font
    %\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \normalfont\large Some Text Above 
    \hrule height 0pt
    \vrule height 9pt width 0pt
    \vbox{\hrule height .8pt width .870\textwidth}
    \hrule height 0pt
    \vrule height 14pt width 0pt
    \vbox{\hrule height 1.1pt width .877\textwidth}
    \hrule height 0pt
    \vrule height 6pt width 0pt
    \hrule height 0pt
    1 6 4 7.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This way I will also set the `\parskip`  to `0pt`  inside the center environment. Otherwise any  previous setting of this length could  ruin your work with the invisible rules.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want; and your response made it easy for me to adjust parameters and see their affect---especially to visualize what vrule does. (+1)
If possible I would like the two lines to look as if they were intended to be the same length (though one is slightly longer than the other), but didn't quite match when laid by hand. Is it possible for the lines to begin at the same horizontal location but end at slightly different horizontal locations rather than being exactly centered?

Comment: That is why I added a `\hrule height 0pt` after each `\vbox{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use rule instead of `\hrule`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \large Some Text Above\\     
    \rule[1ex]{.8\textwidth}{1pt}\\
    \rule[1.9ex]{.7\textwidth}{.6pt}\\[-6pt]
    1 6 4 7
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Whit `\hrule` is also possible but unnecessary more complex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\large Some Text Above\\[-4pt] 
\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule height 1pt width .8\textwidth}\\[-4pt] 
\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule  width .7\textwidth}\\ 
1 6 4 7\par}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for contrasting rule and hrule. This was helpful. (+1)
Ideally, I would like the two lines to have the same horizontal offset rather than be perfectly centered. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BryanM-H Without centering the lines, some like `\hspace*{2cm}\rule....` or  `\hspace*{2cm}\vbox{\hrule ...`  should work.

Comment: @BryanM-H You can also simply set  a  `\parindent2cm` and then  simple write the rules separeted with blank lines (=`\par`), i.e.,  `{\parindent2cm\par\rule[...]{...}{...}\par\rule[...]{...}{...}\par}`. Of course without centering that  part.